# Finding tools/emulator.exe in Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm beginning to develop in Android, but I'm having some problems using Eclipse.

I just reinstalled the current SDK, but when attempting to show Eclipse the path, I get the following error:

> Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)...droid\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe!

I'm pretty sure that I located the correct folder..what exactly happened here? I was told that the new SDK wouldn't pose this problem.

Comment: I installed in `C:\Android` instead of `Program Files (x86)`, and my install puts the emulator in `C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools` (note the missing `-windows` in the SDK folder name). Did you look to see where `emulator.exe` is actually located? It's not really difficult - start Windows Explorer, navigate to the folder you've mentioned in your question (if it exists), and look for `emulator`.

Comment: @Ken White: Yes. It doesn't exist in tools. The only thing in tools is lib.

Comment: Then find it. :-) If you can't, Eclipse can't either. Windows Explorer has a search function. If it's not on your computer, you didn't get the SDK installed correctly. (If you have to reinstall, I'd suggest putting it somewhere else besides `Program Files (x86)`, like a folder location without any spaces in it. The SDK sometimes has issues with spaces in path names, unless they've fixed that recently.)

Comment: @KenWhite: Yeah I couldn't find it. So, I'm just going to reinstall the SDK in the root of C:\ like you suggested.

Comment: @ChrisHarris Which Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: My antivirus quarantined/removed the emulator.exe file, try and get another copy as per the answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Unzip your sdk zip somewhere, copy entire contents of tools directory, replace it with your actual sdk tools folder contents.

Restart eclipse if required.