# Ok button not working in eclipse preferences (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, preferences

Ok button is not displaying in eclipse Preferences(Windows -> preferences)
[please see the SCREEN SHOT](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/61fadb04-c78c-4644-b3d6-bc6d42124842/73c5ebd47bccd177057663a0e1f8b271). I followed [install ADT plugins](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download) but [this error occured](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/9d9a4e08-f1cf-4225-9ce3-ed668bc05905/2939b2d53d89f75c7fc402768e64bee4). What to do?

Answer (score 0):

you should navigate to ...\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\

Comment: i think that the path is wrong. And correct path to the sdk should solve this problem.

Comment: @Dime, the path is correct(from many months i worked on that path). I tried as you said but not working.

Comment: have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224118/finding-tools-emulator-exe-in-eclipse-for-android